# Autoincrement input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html structure like this :

```
<table id="options-table">                  
            <tr>
                <td width="10">No.</td>
                <td>Field 1</td>
                <td>Field 2</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="1" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" /></td>                        
                <td><input type="button" class='del' value='Delete' /></td>
            </tr>                  
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="2"  /></td>
                <td><input type="text"  /></td>
                <td><input type="text"  /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add More" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

And jQuery code like this

```
$('table').on('click','.del', function(){
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                });

                $('table').on('click', '.add', function(){
                    $(this).val('Delete');
                    $(this).attr('class','del');
                    var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input type='text'/></td> <td><input type='text' /></td> <td><input type='text' /></td> <td><input type='button' class='add' value='Add More' /></td></tr>";
                    $("tr:last").after(appendTxt);          
                });
```

How can I add an autoincrementing number in the No. column so every time I add new row that field value will be filled with auto increase number and everytime I delete a row the number(s) below it will be re-calculated.

Here's the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bLpddmw5/)
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add name to you inputs(or it can be a class attribute) like that:
`<input name="number" type="text" value="1"/>`, and then update input values each time you change table.

```
$("input[name='number']").each(function(ind) {
   $(this).val(ind + 1);
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLpddmw5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table id="options-table_2">                  
            <tr>
                <td width="10">No.</td>
                <td>Field 1</td>
                <td>Field 2</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>



        </table>
<table id="options-table">                  
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="1" id="txt_0"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" /></td>                        
                <td><input type="button" class='del' value='Delete' /></td>
            </tr>                  
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="2" id="txt_1"/></td>
                <td><input type="text"  /></td>
                <td><input type="text"  /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add More" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
<script>


$('#options-table').on('click','.del', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    createAll();
});

$('#options-table').on('click', '.add', function(){
    $(this).val('Delete');
    $(this).attr('class','del');
    var rowCount = $('#options-table tr').length;
    var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input type='text'  id='txt_"+rowCount+"'/></td> <td><input type='text' /></td> <td><input type='text' /></td> <td><input type='button' class='add' value='Add More' /></td></tr>";
    $("tr:last").after(appendTxt);   
     updatedata();
});

function updatedata(){
    var rowCount = $('#options-table tr').length;
    for(i=0; i<rowCount; i++){
        $("#txt_"+i).val(i);
    }

}
function createAll(){
    var rowCount = $('#options-table tr').length;
    $('#options-table').html("");
    for(i=0; i<rowCount; i++){
        if(i==(rowCount-1)){
            var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input type='text'  id='txt_"+i+"'/></td> <td><input type='text' /></td> <td><input type='text' /></td> <td><input type='button' class='add' value='Add More' /></td></tr>";
        }else{
            var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input type='text'  id='txt_"+i+"'/></td> <td><input type='text' /></td> <td><input type='text' /></td> <td><input type='button' class='del' value='Delete' /></td></tr>";
        }

        $('#options-table').append(appendTxt);
        $("#txt_"+i).val(i);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A verbal discussion of how/why this works may be helpful to the OP.